# RAR decompression algorithm

Tags: algorithm, compression, rar

I'm looking for the description of an algorithm that can be used to decompress RAR files. I don't need to create new archives, only decompress existing ones.

The Wotsit.org has the description of the RAR [file format](http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?al=R) (version 2), but the description does not describe the decompression algorithm.

Also, does anyone know whether RAR version 3 introduced any significant changes to the file format itself?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get the source for UnRAR at the [WinRAR site](http://www.rarlabs.com/rar_add.htm).

Comment: Okay, now I feel sheepish. I missed that completely. Is this question stupid enough to warrant deleting?

Comment: No, because then I might lose my rep ;-)

Comment: Nope, leave it up.  It will help others.

Comment: @Vojislav: half of the questions on SO are less useful than yours!  Don't be silly.